# Cannot install ubuntu 16.04 on my pc

Tags: 16.04, system-installation

After the process almost finish a prompt pop up and said the installation cannot proceed because grub failed to install. So I choose to installit manually but the prompt does nothing.I tried installing some ubuntu derivatives but nothing.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS install? What brand/model system? May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: I did the boot info thing and these are the results http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/cf7jRzcJCm/

Comment: Are you installing Elementary or Ubuntu?  Is MMC card just data or is this a lightweight system that boots from MMC and then sda is really another drive. What brand/model? This is an Ubuntu only site, so if Elementary cannot help as do not know it. Are you using Something Else and making sure grub bootloader is installed to sda drive?

Comment: The problem was the SD card pluged, after removal Ubuntu install normally. But now I wonder why It tried to install grub on the SD and not in the HDD.Thanks for making me notice that another drive was in.

Comment: That is why I prefer Something Else, but many users just want the auto install option. And with simple systems auto install usually works, but if something not standard then we cannot be sure what the installer is doing.